# TFS SDK Build Projects

Tags: build, msbuild

I'm using TFS SDK and I wrote some code which is getting latest version of the selected project from the server.  Now that I have the code downloaded I would like to invoke a build of the source locally.

Could you give me tutorial or example code on how to do this with MSBuild?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about where you would like to build the source? Do you want to write code to build it locally using msbuild or are you looking to write code to have TFS build this on a build server?

Comment: Already I'm getting the source code on local folder with my other method called "get latest" . After getting latest, I want to build it locally.

Comment: Okay, you want to build these files locally, that is not something that TFS has APIs to do.  Instead, you will likely need to invoke msbuild through some script.  I will update the tags and the text of the question so that someone from the msbuild forum may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will wait for someone else to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TFS Team Build Template to do all the activities

1. Get Latest
2. Compile Code
3. Do other activities like running Unit Test, Code Coverage etc..
4. You can also write custom build activities.

Hope this helps to start

Comment: Yes, I know I can do them with TFS. But I don't know how can I do it? Could you be clearer about Team Build Tempate? Could you explain with examples?